# Как запустить выполнение new Date в обратную сторону?

Tags: javascript, дата, datetime

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при использовании new Date() пользователь видел движение времени назад, а не вперёд, т.е. пользователь заходит на страницу и после вывода реального времени на экран пользователя оно начало идти назад, подскажите, может есть уже какие-то способы или есть решение проблемы

Comment: Берете текущее время и отнимаете в секунду по секунде. Или разницу между начальным и щас.

Comment: Разница не подойдёт, в случае разницы нужно учитывать пройденное время и только потом производить вычитание

Comment: А при вычитании по 1 секунде у меня в цикле выводит ошибку или вообще не работает

Comment: Есть идея закинуть время в строку и потом производить вычитание, но проблема в том, что строка делает время не похожим на время , какой-то набор символов

Comment: Ещё есть идея вычесть из начального времени разность конечного и начального времени, но я не понимаю как работать с датами

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id=mydiv></div>
<script>
var a = new Date().getTime();
var b = new Date();
setInterval(function(){
 b.setTime(a);
 document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = b.toString();
 a -= 1000;
}, 1000);
</script>
```